# Why does this code cause a parse error?

Tags: php, syntax-error

Error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php
>   on line 135

Code:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['d'])
{ // LINE 135 IS THIS ONE
    $d = $_REQUEST['d'];

    if ($d) {
        while (preg_match('/\\\/',$d)) $d = preg_replace('/\\\/','/',$d);
        while (preg_match('/\/\//',$d)) $d = preg_replace('/\/\//','/',$d);
        while (preg_match('/\.\.\//',$d)) $d = preg_replace('/\.\.\//','/',$d);
        if ($d[strlen($d)-1] != '/') $d = $d.'/';
        if ($d == '/') $d = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: `...on line 135` is usually the most helpful part of any error message.

Comment: Yea I know but I did add the line number in the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing a closing bracket:

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['d'] ) )
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed the ). Too much looking at PHP code all day causes this

Answer (score 4):

Yan's got the main answer, but you're also missing a backslash in the first regex:

```
    while (preg_match('/\\\/',$d)) $d = preg_replace('/\\\/','/',$d);
                          ^                              ^
```

The first two insert a literal backslash into the pattern, while the 3rd backslash is actually escaping the pattern delimiter at the end, leading to an unterminated pattern.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! This osFileManager project appears to have so many bugs, issues that need fixing!